# How can i Submit search Results To SQLite table in Android Maps

Tags: android, sqlite, maps, store

I want store the Search place location Into Sqlite database in Android and then i populate in Listview in Android for location serch i am using the the http://maps.google.com/maps? from this i am getting the location by search in Mpas how can i get Lat and Lang from that Adress and submited to Database.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code to Insert the Locations in DB inside the onLocationChanged(Location location) every time when you get new Location it will be stored in the Database as you Desired.

Comment: please give some samples by this i am search the location in Maps Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?"));
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: So Write the code inside the onLocationChanged(Location location) method of LocationChagedListener

Comment: Follow the example given in the link and you will achieve your target.

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();

        TextView txtLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lat);
        txtLat.setText(String.format("%.6f", lat));
        TextView txtLon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lon);
        txtLon.setText(String.format("%.6f", lon));

        MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview1);

Comment: map.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),//1000000), 
            (int)(lon*1E6)));
    }//onLocationChanged

Comment: i added this the app is force closing?

Comment: Have you worked on SQLite and Map before or not. First do some homework first and read the blog (Link I Shared) with consideration.